# gulp-scss is not working for me

Tags: gulp

I am trying to switch from gulp-sass to gulp-scss however surprisinly its not working for me. I have checkedin my code in following Git Hub.

https://github.com/dilipkumar2k6/gulp-sass

"gulp sass" is working because its using gulp-sass module. However "gulp scss" is not working because its using "gulp-scss". Following is my gulp task.

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var scss = require("gulp-scss");

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/application/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/sass'));
});


 gulp.task("scss", function () {
        gulp.src(
            "./src/application/**/*.scss"
        ).pipe(scss(
            {"bundleExec": true}
        )).pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scss'));
    });
```

Comment: This is precisely the reason why i don't use anything based on libsass, support (while better then it was) is still spotty. Use gulp-ruby-sass unless you have a valid reason for needing the extra compile speed or for not installing ruby.

Comment: Thanks, I think i will continue to use gulp-sass. I don't want to install ruby module.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you have to use gulp-scss?

You don't have to use gulp-scss module in order to compile your .scss files.
[gulp-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-scss) is a bit unpopular, you should stick to [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) module and in your code specify ".pipe(sass())" - it will compile either .scss or .sass files down to .css files